# Best practice for casting an inherited object to the correct child class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two class, each of them has several children:

```
class ContainerGeneral {...};
class ContainerTypeA : ContainerGeneral {
public:
    void doSomethingA();
};
class ContainerTypeB : ContainerGeneral {
    void doSomethingB();
};
```

```
class InterpreterGeneral {
protected:
    ContainerGeneral* container;
};

class InterpreterTypeA : InterpreterGeneral {
public:
    void saveContainer(ContainerTypeA* cont) {
        container = cont;
    }
};

class InterpreterTypeB : InterpreterGeneral {
public:
    void saveContainer(ContainerTypeB* cont) {
        container = cont;
    }
};
```

The `Interpreter` classes use to a container of a corresponding type (`A` to `A`, `B` to `B`, `General` to `General`). To do this I added a to `InterpreterGeneral` a member pointer to a `ContainerGeneral` object. I want `InterpreterGeneral` to address this object as a `ContainerGeneral`, but I want that the inherited classes would be able to address the same container as a container of the appropriate type. I can do it by casting the pointer to the inherited class when addressing it (examples only for `A` to save on space):

```
(ContainerTypeA*)container->doSomethingA();
```

Or by adding a new member pointer of the inherited type that would point to the same place as container:

```
class InterpreterTypeA : InterpreterGeneral {
public:
    void saveContainer(ContainerTypeA* cont) {
        containerA = cont;
        container = cont;
    }
    void doSomething() {
        containerA->doSomethingA();
    }
private:
    ContainerTypeA* containerA;
};
```

What is the best practice in this case, and is there a way to do this as clean as possible, without casting every time, and without adding new members that don't hold any "new" information?

Comment: Yes, make a virtual `doSomething` in `ContainerGeneral` and don't bother with inheriting from `InterpreterGeneral`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need concrete type information about the container instance within `InterpreterTypeA` and `InterpreterTypeB`, express this in your code by not storing a `GeneralContainer*` data member in `GeneralInterpreter` (`protected` data member are quite debatable in any case), but instead concrete `ContainerTypeA*` and `ContainerTypeB*` data members in the subclasses `InterpreterTypeA` and `InterpreterTypeB`. Storing a base class pointer and then circumventing its limitation by casting hides the fact that concrete type information is required.

Besides, there is not much wrong with either providing empty default implementations of `doSomethingA()` and `doSomethingB()` in the container base class, or turn them into `virtual` pure member functions and shift the empty implementation into `ContainerTypeA` and `ContainerTypeB`. Then, it's safe to just call them - when it's the undesired concrete type, they won't do anything.

A last, pedantic side note: I don't see any reason to call derived classes in a hierarchy "son" classes. The common term is "child" class.

Comment: I accepted this answer because of the second part, creating empty implementations of `doSomethingA` for `B` and the other way around. I need a pointer to `container` in the parent class because it uses the common function of that class, so the first part doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are dealing with has a solution in the form of [virtual functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/). Try this:

```
class ContainerGeneral {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class ContainerTypeA : public ContainerGeneral {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << "Hello A!" << std::endl;
    };
};

class ContainerTypeB : public ContainerGeneral {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        std::cout << "Hello B!" << std::endl;
    };
};
```

With that you don't need to bother with inheriting from `InterpreterGeneral` at all:

```
class InterpreterGeneral {
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        container->doSomething();
    }
private:
    ContainerGeneral* container;
};
```

**Side note:** This of course generates some runtime overhead. You can avoid it if you don't need polymorphism at runtime. Have a look at [the static polymorphism](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/08/static-polymorphism-in-c/). Only if you're a ninja.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it assumes that `doSomethingA` and `doSomethingB` have something in common, when in fact, they don't have anything in common at all. If I was able to have a function that has a name that makes sense for all children I would use it, but here there is just none. You can assume that the containers are animals and one of them is a bird and the other is a dog, `doSomethingA` is `layAnEgg` and `doSomethingB` is `goForAWalk`. Creating a common function name would mean that the name is meaningless and creates an unreadable code.

Comment: @SIMEL You have to rething your design. You say that they are unrelated and yet it seems that you want to treat them the same in the `InterpreterGeneral` class. That doesn't add up.

Comment: they are related, they are all of the same type and have a lot of shared functionality. It's just that the parts that are different are very different, those are binary files that represent the same initial data in different formats. So the "end user" has the same interface and some of the binary data is the same. But some of the data is entirely different, not just the same data written in a different way, but also each format has data that the other don't.

Comment: @SIMEL So basically each class is a parser, yes? Sounds like a perfect case for virtual functions that accepts a stream and returns an object of common structure.

Comment: Also have a look at [the single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I encourage to use it.